# /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Problem running Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 on openSuSE Leap 15.0
Have no problems with gem installation (or running ruby)

The complete error message is as follows:

> => Booting Puma
>
> => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development
>
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>
> Puma starting in single mode...
>
> - Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
> - Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
> - Environment: development
>
> Exiting
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           41: from bin/rails:3:in `'
>
> ```
>     40: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
>     39: from /home/ikari/workshop/ruby-on-rails/my-app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
>     38: from /home/ikari/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib64/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>     37: from /home/ikari/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib64/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>     36: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
>     35: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
>     34: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
>     33: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
>     32: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
>     31: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
>     30: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
>     29: from /home/ikari/workshop/ruby-on-rails/my-app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>     28: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
>     27: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
>     26: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
>     25: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
>     24: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>     23: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
>     22: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>     21: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
>     20: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
>     19: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
>     18: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
>     17: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
>     16: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
>     15: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
>     14: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
>     13: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
>     12: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
>     11: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
>     10: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
>      9: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
>      8: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
>      7: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
>      6: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:153:in `load_and_bind'
>      5: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
>      4: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
>      3: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse'
>      2: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `add_tcp_listener'
>      1: from /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `new'
> ```
>
> /home/ikari/.gem/ruby/2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Have checked similar questions in StackOverflow that suggested adding libraries:

> 'resolv-replace'
>   and changing files:
>   /etc/hosts
>
> /etc/resolv.conf

But got no solution. I'm starting so I don't have enough knowledge about where I should look. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Solved the problem doing:

> rails server -p 3000 -b 127.0.0.1

But miracles or magic aren't a good explanation. Any ideas where I'm failing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, '> rails server -p 3000 -b 127.0.0.1' works for me too! I had this problem after updating to git. Restart terminal and computer didn't work. Strange and not sure if it is a DNS problem.

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, read the rules of this community.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I don't have 50 reputation enough to make a comment. I just want to support the answer because this is a tricky question.